# Muhammad's Title as Ruler?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history

What was Muhammad's title as ruler of Medina? Looking at his titles, I can't see the one about his temporal governance.

Comment: He had no title other than a prophet and the Muslims of Madinah obeyed their prophet.

Comment: @TheZ What did the non-Muslims living under his rule call him?

Comment: They would call him by his name (Muhammad) or kunya (Abu al-Qasim).

Comment: See the name **اٰمِرٌ/Amir** meaning prince, commander and **ھَادٍ/Haad** meaning the leader.

Comment: @AbduRahman Are you saying he was called the Amir of Medina?

Comment: No! both these names are close to ruler.

Comment: @AbduRahman the correct word is   ,أمير and it also means ruler or a person giving orders.

Comment: @Medi1Saif my bad, I copied the Arabic from a site.